# Touchpad is not working on freya works fine in Windows

Tags: touchpad

I can move the cursor through touchpad.  Which is working fine.  But I can't select it by double click on the touchpad.  Instead of that I can select it by pressing the left click button. Mine Asus x55ca series.  I had no touch pad problem with Windows and ubtuntu.  But working with freya.  Mine touchpad is not ok. I have to press the button whenever I need to select anything. I means it's working partially.  I can able to move the cursor.  But can't select by tapping on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the 'Tap to Click' option in `Application > System Settings > Mouse & Trackpad`

You can also enable Two Finger Scroll in the same applet

If you don't see Mouse & Trackpad, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install switchboard-plug-gcc-mouse
```